# how you could automate this process, time intervals?

Tags: r, survival

how you could automate this process? Divide the variable "t" into periods of 12 days and assign the status at the end of the follow up, keeping the intervals open on the right and closed on the left.

```
id <- c(1,2,3)
t <- c(13, 24, 40)
status <- c(0,1,1)
df <- data.frame(id, t, status)
df
```

```
> df
  id  t status
1  1 13      0
2  2 24      1
3  3 40      1
```

In order to obtein:

```
id time  status
1  0-12)    0
1 [12-24)   0

2   0-12    0
2  [12-24)  0
2  [24-36)  1

3  0-12)    0
3 [12-24)   0
3 [24-36)   0
3 [36-48)   1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A tidyverse approach may look like so. Split your data by `id`, use `cut` to create the interval of 12 days and finally use `tidy::complete` to add the "missing" bins:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

df |>
  split(~id) |>
  lapply(\(x) {
    seq_min <- 0
    seq_max <- 12 * (max(x$t) %/% 12 + 1)
    x <- x |>
      mutate(
        time = cut(t, seq(seq_min, seq_max, 12), right = FALSE),
        .keep = "unused"
      ) |>
      tidyr::complete(id, time, fill = list(status = 0))
    x
  }) |>
  bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#>      id time    status
#>   <dbl> <fct>    <dbl>
#> 1     1 [0,12)       0
#> 2     1 [12,24)      0
#> 3     2 [0,12)       0
#> 4     2 [12,24)      0
#> 5     2 [24,36)      1
#> 6     3 [0,12)       0
#> 7     3 [12,24)      0
#> 8     3 [24,36)      0
#> 9     3 [36,48)      1
```

**EDIT** Here is an updated version which should work for either `right=FALSE` and `right=TRUE`:

```r
df |>
  split(~id) |>
  lapply(\(x, right = TRUE) {
    seq_min <- 0
    seq_max <- if (right) {
      12 * (x$t %/% 12 + (x$t %% 12 > 0)) 
    } else {
      12 * (x$t %/% 12 + 1)
    }
    x <- x |>
      mutate(
        time = cut(t, seq(seq_min, seq_max, 12), right = right),
        .keep = "unused"
      ) |>
      tidyr::complete(id, time, stain, fill = list(status = 0))
    x
  }) |>
  bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 8 × 4
#>      id time    stain status
#>   <dbl> <fct>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1 (0,12]      0      0
#> 2     1 (12,24]     0      0
#> 3     2 (0,12]      1      0
#> 4     2 (12,24]     1      1
#> 5     3 (0,12]      1      0
#> 6     3 (12,24]     1      0
#> 7     3 (24,36]     1      0
#> 8     3 (36,48]     1      1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly.  And to have everything in the same data.frame ??

Comment: Ups. (: Add a final `bind_rows`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Actually `id` is already a fixed variable. (: And like id, simply add it to `complete`, i.e. `complete(id, time, stain, fill = list(status = 0))`

Comment: Stefan. Only one thing more. If I would the intervals close on the right, open on the left, with the same data ... I change (in cut .. right=T)  but the "id=2" has tree rows and must be only two. Where I was wrong??

Comment: id  2 (0,12]     status   0;         id 2 (12,24]   status   1
    id. 2 (24,36]      status 0          this last row would be left over

Comment: Hi Miguel, `right=TRUE` requires a slightly different computation of the max value for the breaks. See my edit for a generalized approach which should account for both cases.